# Can we distribute different versions of same app to different customers using ABM?

Tags: ios, b2b, apple-business-manager

We have a single App ID in Apple Store Connect, which is distributed privately to different organizations.

I have the following scenario: Customer A is on V1, and we have released a new version i.e V2. Now Customer A does not want to move to the new version. Can I simply remove customer A's DEP ID from the new version, so that customer does not get an update but will customer still be able to see the older version i.e V1?

Secondly, is it possible to release different versions to different customers without adding new App ID's in apple store connect?

Comment: If you remove customer A's DEP ID then they can use any already installed apps but they cannot "purchase" any more.  Further those installed apps may be updated to version 2 if they deploy any previously purchased entitlements to new devices or if existing devices have a forced installation of the app via their MDM.  In answer to your second question, you would need to add a new app to App Store Connect with a different bundle ID for the different version

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11. Just one more thing is it the correct/legal way of having different bundle IDs for different versions?

Comment: If you want to have different versions then they need to be different apps, which means different bundle ids.  One of your customers is going to have to remove their current app and install a "new" app (even if it is just to retain the old version).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But is it actually allowed by Apple to have multiple bundle IDs for the same code? I mean will Apple reject another app that is exactly the same app and only bundle ID is different?

Comment: If they were both App Store apps then you might have a problem, but custom apps for different clients should be fine. Apple has a slightly different review process in this case since they understand you are providing apps to meet specific client requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to keep a single app ID and customers can download iPA using iMazing tool and then distribute specific version to devices via MDM or any other way?

Comment: Maybe if they ensure that they only ever distribute the old IPA.  I am not sure if it will work and if the users ever manually update then they will get the new version.

Comment: Is there any sort of notification from ABM to users that an updated version is available on ABM to download? Or any apple connect API is available to fetch latest version available on ABM?

Comment: No.  In my experience if the MDM has flagged the app as "mandatory" then the users will automatically get the new version. If it is optional then they need to manually install the update from their MDM app. This was with intune. Behaviour with other MDMs may vary